# Specializing variadic template with using

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, arithmetic-expressions

Good evening,

I am having trouble with specialzing a variadic template. I need the following template:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using OPT = decltype(operator+(std::declval<Ts>()...))(Ts...);
```

The problem is, this doesn't compile, when I try to use

```
OTP<double,double>
```

so I've tried specializing it via

```
template<>
using OPT<double,double> = double;
```

But now I get the error

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
using OPT<double,double> = double;
```

Does anybody know a way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: clang gives the more helpful error "explicit specialization of alias templates is not permitted"

Comment: Your primary template makes it look like you want `OPT<T...>` to have a function type, but then your attempt at specialization makes `OPT<double, double>` a scalar type?

Comment: if you want to specialize your variadic template, use a class and alias a member type

Comment: also, operator+ doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok, so what I wanted is to get the resulting type of an expression "a+b". If I add two doubles, I get a double, hence my attempt to specialize OTP<double,double>. Maybe there is already an error in defining the template, but how do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a struct behind the hood to implement this, since alias templates can't be specialized and can't refer to themselves.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct sum_type {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<typename sum_type<Ts...>::type>());
};

template <typename T>
struct sum_type<T> {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename... Ts>
using OPT = typename sum_type<Ts...>::type;
```

[Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c1bdbaa6807b0f)